# my code displays Vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, vector

I know this code is probably pretty ugly but i'm really new to programming, when I try to run it, it tells me the Vector subscript is out of range, I have no idea where the problem is. Im pretty sure the error means im using a vector somewhere that doesnt actually have a value assigned to it, but i cant seem to find it anywhere. I have no idea where to go from here. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<vector>
 using namespace std;

double altitude(){
double alti;
cout << "Please input altitude in meters:";
cin >> alti;
return alti;
}
double RoC()
{
double climbR;
cout << "Please input climb rate in m/s:";
cin >> climbR;


return climbR;
}

double speed(){
double v;
cout << "Please input your current speed over ground in m/s" << endl;
cin >> v;
return v;
}

//  Gives you the time it will take to reach desired altitude
double time(double A, double R){
double t;
t = A / R;
return t;
}
//Distance travelled horizontally in given time
double distancetravelled(double Veloc, double Time){

double D;
D = Veloc*Time;

return D;
}
//This will convert time to days, hours, minutes, and seconds.
vector<double> time_to_hours_m_s(double input_seconds){
double days;
double hours;
double minutes;
double seconds;
days = input_seconds / 60 / 60 / 24;
hours = (input_seconds / 60 / 60) / 24;
minutes = (input_seconds / 60) / 60;
seconds = (input_seconds) / 60;
//puts values into a vector
vector<double>times;
times[0] = days;
times[1] = hours;
times[2] = minutes;
times[3] = seconds;

return times;


}


void print_vector(vector<int>converted_time){

cout << "The time it will take for the plane to reach its desired altitude is ";
cout << converted_time[0] << " days, ";
cout << converted_time[1] << " hours, ";
cout << converted_time[2] << " minutes and ";
cout << converted_time[3] << " seconds"; 

}


void print_result (double V, double D){

// This is for the distance it will travell horizontally in the time it takes to to climb.
cout << "The distance over ground you will travel will be ";
cout << D << " meters"<<endl;
}







int main(){
vector < double > converted_time;
double A;
double R;
double T;
double V;
double D;
double days = converted_time[0];
double hours = converted_time[1]; 
double minutes = converted_time[2];
double seconds = converted_time[3];
V = speed();
R = RoC();
A = altitude();
T = time(A, R);

D = distancetravelled(T,V);
time_to_hours_m_s(T);
print_result(V, D);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must size the vector to an appropriate size before you access elements:

```
vector< double > converted_time;
//...
double days = converted_time[0]; // no good
```

You are accessing the first element, but the vector has no elements to access.  The fix would be to make sure the vector is sized first:

```
vector< double > converted_time(4);  // created 4 entries
```